# How to get information about Window's system processes

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to get memory information such as working set size or page fault count of Windows' system processes (svchost, csrss) for an university project.

I'm using winapi's GetProcessMemoryInfo(), but this function works well only on processes that belong to the user (me). I've tried to change the debugging privileges by changing User rights in Windows and with code with AdjustTokenPrivileges() but that doesn't work either.

What else could i do?

EDIT:

The piece of code that i suppose fails is:

```
for (unsigned int c=0;c<vPID.size();c++)
{
    pmc={0};
    hProceso=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,(DWORD)vPID[c]);
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProceso,&pmc,sPMC);
    CloseHandle(hProceso);
    vPMC.push_back(pmc);
}
```

Maybe it's not the best or most efficient code, but i'm developing my idea yet.

vPID is a vector in which i've stored the PIDs. vPMC is a vector in which i'm storing the info for each process.

Comment: Did you remember to run the program "as administrator" ?

Comment: already tried and the program refuses to run instead

Comment: What about a GetWindowThreadProcessId and then OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid); to get the handle and ReadProcessMemory ?

Comment: @headmax: that has nothing to do with querying a process for its memory stats.  Even so, `ReadProcessMemory()` requires the same `PROCESS_VM_READ` right that `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` requires.  You should never use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`, only request the actual rights you really need

Comment: You need to address the problem that prevents the program from running "as administrator".  You can't get information about system processes with admin privilege.

Comment: @ctrl_alt_del: Please show your actual `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` code that is not working.

Comment: I've got it running as admin, but the results are the same...

Comment: @ctrl_alt_del - at first you not show your error code. i guess that `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` on *csrss.exe* - because now it protected process. and without kernel mode help, you can open it only with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and `SYNCHRONIZE`. but if you call `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation)` you got array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` where already exist info which you want

Comment: @RbMm Interesting and absolutely agree with the error code thing. I've previously tried with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION but not along with SYNCHRONIZE. I've been considering ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation) and  NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation) but Microsoft says these functions might be altered in the future, so i wanted to try with something that the people at Microsoft say that is safe.

Comment: @ctrl_alt_del - they write this already 17+ years. this api pefrect worked from nt4 up to latest win 10 build

Comment: @RbMm yes i agree, this api is proven and has worked all this time and I think I will take the approach you're giving me because i'm getting near the deadline i've auto imposed for this project.

Comment: for example some very simply and documented api like `GetVersion` was altered during this time. but this api still not

Comment: @RbMm, why do you use the `Zw` prefix instead of `Nt` for system calls made from user mode? That's functionally the same but not standard because it's misleading. In system calls documented for driver developers, there's a disclaimer that "[i]f the call to this function occurs in user mode, you should use the name "Nt..." instead of "Zw...". You must have seen that thousands of times by now considering your penchant for using the NT API. The `Zw` prefix is used by kernel mode components to call the real `Nt` function, but with the previous mode forced to kernel mode, for many good reasons.

Comment: @eryksun - in user mode no different between `Zw` and `Nt` - both is point to same function. but i use *ntifs.h* header. not all functions here declared. and you can note that with `Zw` prefix functions declared more frequently compare `Nt`. say `ZwMapViewOfSection` declared, when `NtMapViewOfSection` - not. or for registry api - all declared only with `Zw` prefix (with `Nt` not exported from kernel). some api, like `ZwClose` and `NtClose` declared in both variants. so i for make live easy prefer use declaration from system headers, when it exist.

Comment: @eryksun - another task, when we call this api from kernel - need very carefully select which version *Nt* or *Zw* use (if both exported), because here big differece